# How to hide print button and other content on print page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide print button and some text when print a page. I have following files:

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="estimated-fleet-page">
        <div id="container">
            <h2>Summary Report</h2>

            <div id="button-container">
                <a href="#" id="PrintDiv" class="btn btn-success btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>Print</a>
            </div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

js part

```
$('#PrintDiv').click(function(){
    var contents = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML;
    var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
    frame1.name = "frame1";
    frame1.style.position = "absolute";
    frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
    document.body.appendChild(frame1);
    var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
    frameDoc.document.open();
    frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
    frameDoc.document.write(contents);
    frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
    frameDoc.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.frames["frame1"].focus();
        window.frames["frame1"].print();
        document.body.removeChild(frame1);
    }, 500);
    return false;
})
```

Output:

[image]

How can I remove the print button and the content above the "Summary Report" of the picture above.

I have posted the issue in jsfiddle as well.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/zan/b780Lcte/2/
```

Thank you

Comment: checkout this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_printing.htm

Comment: Use a print stylesheet, and hide the required elements in it

Comment: @nas, why do you ask your question twice ?

Comment: @DomeTune, because i tried every solution but still i get same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jquery you can hide the print button when clicked and show it back after print with:

```
$('#PrintDiv').click(function(){
$(this).hide();
        var contents = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML;
        var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
        frame1.name = "frame1";
        frame1.style.position = "absolute";
        frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
        document.body.appendChild(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
      $('#PrintDiv').show();
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            document.body.removeChild(frame1);
        }, 500);
        return false;
})
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtvtv5L6/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your print function to :

```
window.print();
```

Add css below :

```
@media print {
    #button-container {
        display :  none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add hide() function.

```
$('#PrintDiv').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this but not working. Check the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `document.getElementById("print").style.display = 'none';`

Comment: No this one not worked

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, hope you can fix it :D

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use Bootstrap.
Did you try to use the helper classes ?
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-print

```
<div id="button-container" class="hidden-print">
    <a href="#" id="PrintDiv" class="btn btn-success btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>Print</a>
</div>
```

the `hidden-print` css class should hide the container when printing

Updated the fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/b780Lcte/9/

Without bootstrap you can create your own class :

```
@media print {
  .hidden-print {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Of course you have to use the `window.print()` function to let it interprete the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: did you opened the fiddle?

Comment: edited the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

With media queries, you could add css rules such as `display:none;` when the page is being printed.

```css
@media print { 
    /* All your print styles go here */

    #PrintDiv{
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

This way, you could also hide the page's banner or remove the background, make the text color black or such things. **Note that changes will not be visible inside the browser : they are only effective when your page is being printed.** If your want to see how it looks like without to really print you page, the easier way is to click your print button or hit `Ctrl+P` inside Google Chrome because they offer you a live representation of what is going to be print.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS to achieve what you want to do (hide print button and any other content on print page)

Please add **no-print** class to any element that you want to hide on a print page.

```
@media print {
    .no-print
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```